# The derivative of a real valued function whose domain in a function space

Tags: calculus, analysis, banach-spaces

I am struggling to follow an example of the derivative of a function whose domain is a function space. My question concerns in particular Example 1.1.6 taken from Pierre Schapira's online lecture notes for differential calculus on Banach spaces, which can be found here

https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~pierre.schapira/lectnotes/

The passage I am struggling with is at the top of page 10; in particular, I cannot obtain the constant C with the property that $|\epsilon(\phi(t), \psi(t))| \leq C|\psi(t)|$. Applying the mean value theorem he quotes above seems to yield

$|\ln(\phi(t)+\psi(t)) - \ln(\phi(t)) - \frac{\psi(t)}{\phi(t)}| \leq |\psi(t)|\cdot M$

where $M = \sup_{\xi \in [-1, 1]}|\ln'(\phi(t)+\xi\psi(t)) - \ln'(\phi(t))|$.

Now from (1.3) we have that $|\ln(\phi(t)+\psi(t)) - \ln(\phi(t)) - \frac{\psi(t)}{\phi(t)}| = |\psi(t)||\epsilon(\phi(t), \psi(t))|$

and hence

$|\psi(t)||\epsilon(\phi(t), \psi(t))| \leq |\psi(t)|\cdot M$.

Now since $\psi > 0$ this gives us $|\epsilon(\phi(t), \psi(t))| \leq M$ and I cannot seem to convert this into an expression of the form $|\epsilon(\phi(t), \psi(t))| \leq C|\psi(t)|$ where C does not depend on $t$.

In my frustration, I attempted a more direct approach to the obtaining the result

$\ln(\phi + \psi) - \ln(\phi) - \frac{\psi}{\phi} = ||\psi||\alpha(\phi, \psi)$

where $\alpha(\phi, \psi) \to 0$ as $\psi \to 0$.

Let, as suggested, $\alpha$ be the function $\alpha(\phi, \psi)(t) = \frac{|\psi(t)|}{||\psi||}\epsilon(\phi(t), \psi(t))$.  We have, since $\frac{|\psi(t)|}{||\psi||}$ is bounded by 1, that

$|\alpha(\phi, \psi)(t)| \leq |\epsilon(\phi(t), \psi(t))|$.

Now since $|\psi(t)| \leq ||\psi||$ it seems clear that as $||\psi|| \to 0$ we must have $|\psi(t)| \to 0$ independently of $t$ and thus, by the definition of $\epsilon(\phi(t), \psi(t))$ we have that

$|\alpha(\phi, \psi)(t)| \leq |\epsilon(\phi(t), \psi(t))| \to 0$ as $||\psi|| \to 0$

as required.

I've been playing around with this for a while now and I'm sure my error will be suitably embarrassing, but any help with either my original problem or comments regarding my alternative would be *greatly* appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand any of this sort of mathematics, but +1 for a question with lots of faithful work shown.

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit, I didn't fully read through all the details, simply because everything is being done with the particular function $\ln$, which makes it hard (for me anyways) to keep track of what steps are true in general and what holds in this special case. But, as a general setup, we can state the following:

> **Theorem (Special case of Henri Cartan: Differential Forms, Chapter 2, Proposition 1.2.2)** Let $V$ be a real Banach space, fix an interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$, let $E = \mathcal{C^0}([a,b], V)$ (set of continuous maps, equipped with the supremum norm). Let $A$ be an open subset of $V$, and suppose we are given a $\mathcal{C}^k$ function $F: A \to \mathbb{R}$ ($k \geq 1$). Then, the set $U = \{ \varphi \in E : \text{image}(\varphi) \subset A\}$ is open in $E$. Now, define the map $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ by
>   \begin{equation}
> f(\varphi) = \int_a^b F(\varphi(t)) \, dt
> \end{equation}
>   Then $f$ is also of class $\mathcal{C^k}$, and its derivative at a point $\varphi \in U$ (which is a bounded linear map from $E$ to $\mathbb{R}$),  evaluated at $\psi \in E$ is given by the equation
>   \begin{equation}
> df_{\varphi}(\psi) = \int_a^b dF_{\varphi(t)}(\psi(t)) \, dt.
> \end{equation}

In the particular example you were looking at we had: $V = \mathbb{R}$, $[a,b] = [0,1]$, $A = (0, \infty), F = \ln$; so it should be easy to see how the general formula of this theorem reduces to the one presented in those notes.

To prove $U$ is open, use the fact that for a given $\varphi \in U$, its image is a compact subset of  the open set $A$; hence by the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood theorem, (which is valid in any metric space), there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that the $\varepsilon$ neigbourhood of $\text{image}(\varphi)$ lies in $A$. It follows that if $\lVert \psi - \varphi\rVert < \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$, then $\psi \in U$.

Next, the difficult part is showing $f$ is differentiable. Deducing that $f$ is $\mathcal{C^k}$ is pretty straightforward from the formula for the derivative; use induction on $k$ (for these details, I highly recommend reading Henri Cartan's book; he does an amazing job there).

Assuming $f$ is differentiable, the formula for the derivative is easy to obtain, because differentiability at $\varphi$ implies that for every $\psi \in E$, the directional derivative $(D_{\psi}f)(\varphi)$ exists with the following relationship:
\begin{align}
df_{\varphi}(\psi) &= (D_{\psi}f)(\varphi) \\
&= \dfrac{d}{dx} \bigg\rvert_{x=0} f(\varphi + x \psi) \\
&= \dfrac{d}{dx} \bigg\rvert_{x=0} \int_a^b F\left( \varphi(t) + x \cdot \psi(t) \right) \, dt \\
&= \int_a^b \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \bigg\rvert_{x=0} F\left( \varphi(t) + x \cdot \psi(t) \right) \, dt \\
&= \int_a^b dF_{\varphi(t)} \left( \psi(t) \right) \, dt
\end{align}

I used the typical abuse of notation which comes up in this context, and in the $4^{th}$ equal sign, I made use of the Leibniz integral rule for differentiating under the integral sign.

(If you still wish to see why $f$ is differentiable, let me know; I'll try to outline it as best I can)